# Which is the most recommended Pretty-print tables module in python?

Tags: python, table

I have looked at various python modules like `tabulate`, `texttable`, `terminaltables`, `prettytable` and `asciitable`. It seemed that tabulate is the most commonly used module but the problem with `tabulate` is it doesn't support multiline rows like `texttable`

[image]

When the length of column is long, then the output is rendered in a really bad way in `tabulate`. `Textable` seems to do a better job in that case. In conclusion, from my research I felt that texttable seems to be a better choice than other modules. I want to know what others suggestions are.